# django upload image gives InMemoryUploadedFile error on validating

Tags: django, image, upload

I am trying to make an upload image form. but it crashes on a succesfull clean in ym form (get 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get')

My form clean:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings

def clean(self):
    content = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
    content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
    if content_type in settings.CONTENT_TYPES:
        if content._size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(content._size)))
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported'))
    return content
```

my setting attributes:

```
MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 1310720
CONTENT_TYPES = ['image']
```

The errors work fine. but when no ValidationError is found i get that InMemory error.
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've returned `self.cleaned_data['avatar']` from `def clean()` which should be `def clean_avatar()`. `clean()` should return the whole `cleaned_data` anyhow.